# How to add 'T' to UTC timestamp without T and also add 5 mins to it

Tags: java

I wan to convert the string d (date in UTC format) to String in UTC format with 'T' and increment 5 mins to time. Below is the code

```
    public static void main (String args[]) throws ParseException
{
    String d="2021-08-27 06:25:00.716241+00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX");
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date actualDate = format.parse(d);  
    String a=format1.format(actualDate);
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

I get output as 2021-08-27T12:06:56 but I need String 'a' as  2021-08-27T06:25:00 and then add 5 mins to it and make it 2021-08-27T06:30:00
Please help

Comment: Did you try adding 5 minutes to `actualDate`? And did you have at the newer `java.time` API which exists since Java 8 and makes things _a lot_ easier?

Comment: (1) I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) There is no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can process your string since it supports only milliseconds, exactly three decimals on the seconds, and you have got six decimals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String d = "2021-08-27 06:25:00.716241+00:00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.SSSSSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(d, dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String str = odt.format(dtfOutput);
        System.out.println(str);

        // Add 5 minutes to it
        odt = odt.plusMinutes(5);
        str = odt.format(dtfOutput);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-27T06:25:00
2021-08-27T06:30:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/batPp0)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I need to retain seconds as well here that is instead of 2021-08-27T06:25 it should be 2021-08-27T06:25:00

Comment: @SamMaul - This is what I have done in my solution. Please check the output and let me know if there is any doubt.

Comment: @SamMaul Are you sure? Your desired format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). According to the ISO 8601 standard the seconds are optional. So the consumer of your string should accept it with or without seconds.